Getting wrong answer for cube-root procedure in Scheme
I wrote this code to compute the cube root of a number in Scheme:
(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (abs x) (if (< x 0) (- x) x))
(define (cube x) (* x x x))
(define (cube-root-itr guess x) 
  (if (good-enough? guess x) guess 
     (cube-root-itr (improve guess x) x)))
(define (improve guess x) (/ (+ (* 2 guess) (/ x (square guess))) 3))
(define (good-enough? guess x) (< (abs (- (cube guess) x)) 0.0000000001))
(define (cube-root x) (cube-root-itr 1.0 x))
(cube-root 9)

It returns: 2.080083823051904
Why doesn't it return a more precise answer? And how can I make it better? This is Exercise 1.8 in the SICP book.

Which more precise answer did you expect? I think that's as close as you get with 32-bit floats.

This program is completely correct, the returned value is indeed the cube root of 9, or as close as you can get.
